# Ajax call with javascript not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to try to get some value from page cart.php from and ajax call, but its not working.
Ajax code is below:

```
function temp_sell(id) {
    //var p_id=document.getElementById('temp').value;
    alert(p_id);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "temp_sell.php",
        data: "value=" + p_id,
        success: function (message) {
            alert(message);
            $("#your_cart").html(message);
        }
    });
}
```

temp_sell.php is below where I want to show some products details

```
<?php 
include("connection.php");
echo $p_id = $_POST['value'];
$qty=1;
$query="SELECT * FROM product WHERE id='$p_id'";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    ?>
            <form>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <img src="<?php echo "img/".$data['image'];?>"/>
                    <strong><?php echo $data['pro_name'];?></strong>
                    <strong><?php echo $data['price'];?></strong>
                    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $qty;?>"/>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
    <?php
    }                   
?>
```

Comment: And php code where is?

Comment: are you getting error?

Comment: Please show your php code.

Comment: Also, tell is if the alert is displaying.

Comment: Is the alert displaying? fucntion is passed id but seems to use p_id which isn't declared

Comment: `p_id` is undefined, you have commented the `p_id` value or change `temp_sell(p_id)`

Comment: its all working i have the p_id but its just don't go to temp_sell.php

Comment: id will be p_id but it still not working

Comment: @ForhadSikder: After a quick look at your profile, you might want to consider _accepting an answer_ every now and then. People will be more helpful if you show your appreciation for their efforts. If you don't know how accepting an asnwer works, [here's how to do it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Can you post your html part here ?

Answer (score 1):

`p_id` is undefined, you have commented the `p_id` value or change temp_sell(p_id).

```
function temp_sell(p_id)
```

instead of

```
function temp_sell(id)
```

Reference comments : [Ajax call with javascript not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040566/ajax-call-with-javascript-not-working#comment31632135_21040566)

Comment: yes i correct it but still not working i can't get anything from temp_sell.php

Comment: @ForhadSikder: because, as the 2 other answers explain, you're not fetching the resultset as an associative array (`while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result))` should be `while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))`)

Comment: did you get the `alert` when you call that function. Make sure your jquery libaray path is correct. Checck your browser console, it maythrough some errors if any

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
function temp_sell(id){
var p_id=document.getElementById('temp').value; // <--- uncomment this line
alert(p_id);
$.ajax({
         type: "POST", 
         url: "temp_sell.php",
         data: {value:p_id}, // <--- change this
         success: function(message){ 
         alert(message);
         $("#your_cart").html(message);
        }       
       });
   }
```

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` — Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both

Comment: thank you, I did not know it, but user is still wrong, because `MYSQL_ASSOC)` should be as the second argument of `mysql_fetch_array`, to return a associative array

Comment: By default, it fetches both, but you can pass second parametr based on your need.

Comment: @KrishR: either way, sure the fetching works using the default behaviour of `mysql_fetch_array`, but it won't work for long... once the ancient extension is finally removed, the code won't work anyway. In fact, it will already issue `E_DEPRECATED` notices on up-to-date systems

Comment: I updated my answer, thank you @KrishR, after 3 years of php programming, I didn't know that :)